# How is this code rounding the value to the lowest whole number?

Tags: python

This question was in Leetcode to find odd numbers between an interval(inclusive).

**Given two non-negative integers low and high. Return the count of odd numbers between low and high (inclusive).**

One of the efficient codes are:

```
class Solution(object):
     def countOdds(self, low, high):
        high = high + 1
        c = high/2 - low/2
        return c
```

What I do not understand is how does the code return 1 as an answer when the input is low = 8 and high =10. Shouldn't the answer have been 1.5? I do not understand what specifically makes the code round the value of 'c' to the lowest whole number.

Comment: This look like Python 2 code. In Python 3 you would use // for integer division.

Comment: 10/2 - 8/2 is 1, is there a reason you're expecting 1.5?

Comment: If Python 2 is used to execute this, `/` may be integer division (if `low` and `high` are integers).

Comment: why is the count 1.5? shouldn't it be 1, as their is only 1 odd number between 8 and 10. also when i run the code in python 3, i get 1.5

Comment: I think I got it. It is because there is an option for python and Python3. I used python option so it prolly uses python2! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This definitely would not work for `low > high`. Also I expect that this is Python 2, so in Python # 3 we would need to use `//`

## Does it work in other cases

For `low < high` we can prove correctness by splitting the proof to pairs `(low, high)` being `(even, even)`, `(even, odd)`, `(odd, even)`, `(odd, odd)`.

### Used notations and equations

`k`,`l` are some integers.

Every even number can be written as `2k` for some integer `k`.

Every odd number can be written as `2k + 1` for some integer `k`.

There are `high - low + 1` numbers between `low` and `high` including bounds.

For integer division it holds `2k // 2 = (2k + 1) // 2 = k` for any integer k.

### (odd, even), (even, odd)

In this case we have regular sequence of (odd, odd+1 = even) or (even, even+1 = odd). Number of odd numbers is half of all `(high - low + 1) / 2`

The program is not so symmetric:

#### `(even, odd)`

Let `high = 2k + 1` and `low = 2l` for some integer `k` and `l`.

`c  = (high + 1) // 2 - low // 2`, where `//` denotes integral division.

Expressing parity with integers `k` and `l` and using integral division:

`c = (2k + 1 + 1) // 2 - (2l) // 2 = k - l + 1`

Comparing with `(high - low + 1) / 2`

`(2k + 1 - 2l + 1) / 2 = k - l + 1`

#### `(odd, even)`

`c  = (high + 1) // 2 - low // 2 = (2k + 1) // 2 - (2l + 1) // 2 = k - l`

Comapring with `(high - low + 1) / 2`

`(2k - (2l + 1) + 1) = k - l`

### `(even, even)`

It is the same number of odd numbers as for (even, even - 1) which is (even, odd) case and the count is then `(high - low) / 2`

Let `high = 2k` and `low = 2l` for some integer `k` and `l`. The program returns:

`c = (2k + 1) // 2 - (2l) // 2 = k - l`

Comparing with `(high - low) / 2`

`(2k - 2l) / 2` = k - l

### `(odd, odd)`

It is the same number of odd numbers as for (odd, odd + 1) which is (odd, even) case and the count is then `(high - low + 2) / 2 = (high - low) / 2 + 1`

Let `high = 2k + 1` and `low = 2l + 1` for some integer `k` and `l`. The program returns:

`c = (2k + 2) / 2 - (2l + 1) / 2 = k - l + 1`

Comparing with `(high - low) / 2 + 1`

`(2k + 1 - 2l - 1) / 2 + 1 = k - l + 1`

## `low = high`

### Even `low = high`

The correct answer is 0. The program returns

`(2k + 1) // 2 - (2k) // 2 = 0`

### Odd `low = high`

The correct answer is 1. The program returns

`(2k + 2) // 2 - (2k) // 2 = 1`

Q.E.D